# Long arithmetic addition implemented in functional style

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, babel.js

This implementation uses ECMA6 syntax and babel as transpiler. You can use this code to add integers which are bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

```
var _ = require('underscore'),
    assert = require('assert');

var strAdd = function(lnum, rnum) {
  var {rem, res} = _.chain(
    _.zip(
      lnum.split('').reverse(),
      rnum.split('').reverse()
    )
  ).reduce(
    ({rem, res}, [left, right]) => {
      var sum = Number(left || 0) + Number(right || 0) + rem;
      res.push(
        sum % 10
      );
      return {
        res,
        rem: ~~(sum/ 10)
      };
    },
    {
      rem: 0,
      res: []
    }
  ).value();
  if (rem !== 0) {
    res.push(rem);
  }
  return res.reverse().join('');
};
assert(strAdd('1', '9') === '10', strAdd('1', '9'));
assert(strAdd('1', '0') === '1', strAdd('1', '0'));
assert(strAdd('5', '5') == '10');
assert(strAdd('2', '2') === '4');
assert(strAdd('20', '202') === '222');
```

Comment: This is not *Long arithmetic* but *Variable precision arithmetic*!

Comment: That's much better.

Answer (score 1):

#### Input validation

The function will happily return non-sense result when an argument contains not only digits.
Unless you are absolutely certain that this function is used in a safe context,
it would be good to validate the inputs.

Going even further,
I would create a `validate` function that returns a number or else throws an exception, and call it after splitting:

```
  lnum.split('').map(validate).reverse(),
  rnum.split('').map(validate).reverse()
```

This way the summing step will not need anymore the `Number` conversions,
 a bit simpler:

```
  var sum = (left || 0) + (right || 0) + rem;
```

#### Cleverness

I find this clever, but hacky:

> ```
> rem: ~~(sum/ 10)
> ```

I suggest to just spell out the intention nicely:

```
rem: sum > 9 ? 1 : 0
```

On the other hand, instead of this:

> ```
> if (rem !== 0) {
> ```

Since the value of `rem` is guaranteed to be either 0 or 1,
I think it's totally fine to be lazy and rely on the truthiness:

```
if (rem) {
```